# getting wrong data from PHP to android

Tags: php, android

I am trying out a registration module where I check whether the user is already registered or not. When I run this script through browser if works perfectly. But when I get the response through android it always returns -1. But the insertion is still happening. I have went through all the possibilities of check. Any suggestions why it is happening?

```
    require_once "config.php";
    $fullname = $_REQUEST['fullname'];
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $phone_no = $_REQUEST['phone'];
    $status = "pending";
    $password = $_REQUEST['password'];
    $forgot_password = "";
    $options = ['cost' => 11, 'salt' => mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM) ];
    $password=password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
    $created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $modified = $created;  

    $sql="SELECT `id` FROM `Login` WHERE `email`='$email'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);


    $count=0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){


        $count++;
     }

     if($count>0){
         //User already registered
         echo "-1";

     }else{

         $q = "INSERT INTO `Login`(`id`,`fullname`,`email`,`phone_no`,`status`,`password`,`forgot_password`,`created`,`modified`) VALUES('','$fullname','$email','$phone_no','$status','$password','$forgot_password','$created','$modified')";
    $s = mysql_query($q);
    if($s){
        $sql="SELECT `id` FROM `Login` WHERE `email`='$email'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $id=$row['id'];
         }

        $sql= "INSERT INTO `profile`(`id`,`firstname`,`lastname`,`gender`,`DOB`,`address`,`state`,`city`,`pincode`,`nationality`,`mobilenumber`,`email`,`scores`) VALUES('$id','$fullname','','','','','','','','','','','')";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if (!$result) {
            //failed to insert
            echo "0";
        }
        else {
            //Success
            echo "1";
        }
    }

     }

   mysql_close($con);
```

the android part of call..

```
new LoadUrl().execute("www.example.com/register.php");


private class LoadUrl extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            Log.e("result", "Do In Background");
            UrlLoader urlLoader=new UrlLoader(urls[0]);
            output=urlLoader.load(jsonString);
            return output;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            String output=result.replaceAll("[\n\t]", "").trim();
            Log.e("Output",output);



            if(output.equals("1")){
                Log.e("Location","Sign Up Success");

            }else if(output.equals("-1")){
                Log.e("Location","Duplicate User");


            }else{
                Log.e("Location","Sign Up Failed");

            }
        }


    }
```

LOG

```
09-12 19:54:24.696    4570-4570/com.test.imagecrop E/Email﹕ jrheh@dhjggrd
09-12 19:54:24.696    4570-4570/com.test.imagecrop E/password﹕ svshe
09-12 19:54:24.697    4570-4570/com.test.imagecrop E/confirmPass﹕ vshehehw
09-12 19:54:24.697    4570-4570/com.test.imagecrop E/fullName﹕ hdjrue
09-12 19:54:24.697    4570-4570/com.test.imagecrop E/Phone﹕ 615154846
09-12 19:54:24.699    4570-4643/com.test.imagecrop E/result﹕ Do In Background
09-12 19:54:24.700    4570-4643/com.test.imagecrop E/Location﹕ Set URL
09-12 19:54:24.700    4570-4643/com.test.imagecrop E/Location﹕ Load method
09-12 19:54:24.700    4570-4643/com.test.imagecrop E/Location﹕ [{"attrName":"email","attrVal":"jrheh@dhjggrd"},{"attrName":"password","attrVal":"svshe"},{"attrName":"phone","attrVal":"615154846"},{"attrName":"fullname","attrVal":"hdjrue"}]
09-12 19:54:24.700    4570-4643/com.test.imagecrop E/Location﹕ check1
09-12 19:54:24.702    4570-4643/com.test.imagecrop E/Location﹕ Before Execute
09-12 19:54:27.940    4570-4643/com.test.imagecrop E/Location﹕ After Execute
09-12 19:54:27.941    4570-4570/com.test.imagecrop E/result﹕ -1
09-12 19:54:27.941    4570-4570/com.test.imagecrop E/Output﹕ -1
09-12 19:54:27.941    4570-4570/com.test.imagecrop E/Output Length﹕ 2
09-12 19:54:27.941    4570-4570/com.test.imagecrop E/Location﹕ Duplicate User
```

Comment: What is the output of `Log.e("Output",output);`

Comment: @scorpion E/Output﹕ -1

Comment: Comment these lines in php file and check:
`echo mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "<br>";
echo  $row['id'];`

Comment: those were added to test it. No luck of removing it.

Comment: I wonder that it returns -1 and still inserting the data

Comment: If you comment all the code below `echo mysql_num_rows($result);` in php file, what output do you get then for `Log.e("Output",output);`

Comment: Chech out my updated question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89487/discussion-between-scorpion-and-dharanbro).